# Prevent AutoCompleteTextView from showing the result in its own box

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using an AutoCompleteTextView to show a list of items the user can select. When the users selects an item, this selected item fills a ListView just below the AutoCompleteTextView. So far so good.

The issue: after the selection of the item out of the AutoCompleteTextView, the AutoCompleteTextView body itself (this "text-box") gets filled up with some text, which is the SimpleCursorAdapter resource (the actual text showing up is: android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter@4107d010).

What I wish to have: I want the AutoCompleteTextView to refresh and show no text in its own body so the user can immediately type in more text and select further items out of the drop-down list.

Could you please give me a hint how I could achieve that?

Added information:

Thank you Kyle. What I did was to extend SimpleCursorAdapter to SimpleCursorAdapterNoText. I then overridden convertToString() just like you said. I didn't change BindView because I read the documentation twice but I still don't understand what I should change in BindView. Any way - This didn't save the problem - I still get the same string in the AutoComplete. Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void populateListView()
{
   // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
  Cursor tournamentXCursor = mDbHelper.retrieveTrounamentX(mRowId);
  startManagingCursor(tournamentXCursor);

  // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only name)
  String[] from = new String[] {StournamentConstants.TblX.TBL_COLUMN_X_NAME};

  // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just name)
  int[] to = new int[]{R.id.competitor_row};

  // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
  SimpleCursorAdapterNoText tournamentX = new SimpleCursorAdapterNoText(this, R.layout.competitor_row, tournamentXCursor, from, to);

  tournamentX.convertToString(tournamentXCursor);
  setListAdapter(tournamentX);      
}
```

Anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong?

EDITED:
This is my inherited SimpleCursorAdapter class

```
 public class SimpleCursorAdapterNoText extends SimpleCursorAdapter 
{
    public SimpleCursorAdapterNoText(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) 
    {
    //Empty string so AutoComplete shows no text
    return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    }
}
```

I changed my calling code and eliminated

```
tournamentX.convertToString(tournamentXCursor);
```

I was convinced it is essential that I not only override it in my subclass but that I also use it in my calling code so the text inside the AutoComplete will be eliminated.

I am sag to say the this still didn't help - I keep on getting android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41377578 in the AutoCompleteBox just after I select one item off the AutoComplete selection list.

Thanks D.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to clear the text when a user clicks on an item in the dropdown list, define the AutoComplete as a member variable and override it's setOnItemClickListener.  Like this:

```
mAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mAutoComplete.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Sam,This works perfectly! :) I would vote it up but I am so young in this forum that I don't even have the permission for that. Thumbs up - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a simplecursoradapter to fill the textView, you will need to subclass it and override the following method. You will probably also have to override bindview.

```
@Override
public CharSequence convertToString (Cursor cursor){
   return "";
}
```

You need to put the above inside your SimpleCursorAdapterNoText class, not call it from the top level code.

```
class extends SimpeCursorAdpaterNotText{
// ... whatever other code you have here
@Override
    public CharSequence convertToString (Cursor cursor){
       return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work. I did as Kyle instructed (see update in my original post) but I didn't touch BindView as I lack the understanding what I should change there. Any further ideas?

Comment: What happened? Did your drop down items all appear blank?

Comment: Hi Kyle, please look at my original post - I added some details.